# _TypeError (type 'newsPostDetails' is not a subtype of type 'String')" when I call " _getNewsPostDetails() async { await DatabaseService()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im calling _getNewsPostDetails, but I keep getting an exception stating  "_TypeError (type 'newsPostDetails' is not a subtype of type 'String')" when I call " _getNewsPostDetails() async {  await DatabaseService()"

Here is getNewsPostDetails in DatabaseService()

```
    Future getNewsPostDetails(String newsPostId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('newsPosts')
        .where('newsPostId', isEqualTo: newsPostId)
        .get();
    final newsPostData = snapshot.docs[0].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    newsPostDetails postDetails = newsPostDetails(
      newsPostTitle: newsPostData['newsPostTitle'] as String?,
      newsPostContent: newsPostData['newsPostContent'] as String?,
      date: newsPostData['date'] as String?,
    );
    print("getNewsPostDetails Complete");
    return postDetails;
  }
```

And here is class newsPostDetails incase you need it

```
class newsPostDetails {
  final String? newsPostTitle;
  final String? newsPostContent;
  final String? date;

  newsPostDetails({this.newsPostTitle, this.newsPostContent, this.date});
}
```

Here is what the firestore looks like:

[image: firestore]

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show a screenshot of that document on firestore

Comment: @Gwhyyy - Edited with picture

Comment: it seems fine, can you include a sample of where did you used this method and where do you assign the getNewsPostDetails mathod